# Stop Chrome from suggesting Addresses with HTML while using Google Places Autofill

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, frontend

Given the following input:

```
 <input id="residential-address" placeholder="Residential Address" autocomplete="off" type="search" />
```

I continue to see addresses recommended:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I see that my browser setting tell Chrome to autofill, but then google's own location autocomplete widget UX becomes broken (with autofill overlapping the [autocomplete][2] widget).

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

What's the proper way to go about telling the browser to back off here?

Autocomplete code (works):

```
var initAutocomplete = function (inputId) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById(inputId)),
        { types: ['geocode'] });
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () { handleAddress(this) });
    return autocomplete;
}
```

Setting the `autocomplete="new-password"` doesn't work; I see it get reverted to `off` on load, and autofill persists.

Comment: @NayeemAzad the solutions there do not work with the current version of chrome, at least in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Simply changing the `id` to NOT include `address` is what fixed it for me.  Thanks, Google, for injecting your opinions and random features into my projects and giving me more work.  Stop trying to be "clever".

Comment: I found I had to remove references to address in `id`, `placeholder`, and `name` for this to work

Comment: It appears this Chrome "feature" has become more aggressive... I also had to remove City and Zip from the placeholder. The site redfin.com somehow has this figured out but I don't see what they're doing differently.

Comment: @AlexR you can try wrapping every input element in a form tag (individually) and setting each of them to autocomplete="off". Google PMs really need some developer empathy training or something.